# Validate select tag that uses a controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model-view-controller, embedded-ruby

My forms work fine but I keep getting `undefined method empty? for nil:NilClass` on my select tags whenever I add form validations. I found that the fact that I'm putting controller variables into the select function on the form is causing the problem.

I have a long array of options for the select tags so even though I know it would work if I just paste the arrays in the select function I want to find a way to keep it as clean as I have it now

Here's my controller

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_member, only: [:edit, :update, :delete, :destroy]
  before_action :form_vars, only: [:new, :edit, :executives]

  def find_member
    @members = Member.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...

  def new
    @members = Member.new
  end

  def create
    @members = Member.new(members_params) #the new Members entry is recreated through the strong params method
    @members.is_executive = true #Remove for members feature
    if @members.save #if the entry saves
      redirect_to({ action: 'executives' }, notice: @members.first_name + ' ' + @members.last_name + ' has been created!') #show all of the present entries
    else
      render({ action: 'new' }) #redisplay the create an entry page
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my form

```
<div class="forms">
    <%= form_for(@members) do |member| %>
        <small>* = Required</small>
    <label>First Name*</label><br>
    <%= member.text_field :first_name %><br>
    <label>Last Name*</label><br>
    <%= member.text_field :last_name %><br>
    <label>LinkedIn Profile Address</label><br>
    <%= member.url_field :linkedinurl %><br>
        <label>Photo*</label><br>
        <%= member.file_field :avatar %><br>
    <%= member.label 'Major*' %><br>
    <%= member.select(:major, @major, selected: @members.major, prompt: 'Select Major') %><br>
    <label>E-Mail*</label><br>
    <%= member.text_field :email %><br>
    <label>Graduation Date</label><br>
    <%= member.select(:graduation_date, [1], selected: @members.graduation_date, prompt: 'Month') %>
        <%= member.select(:graduation_date, Date.today.year..Date.today.year+5, prompt: 'Year') %><br>
    <!-- <%= member.label(:is_executive, "Is this member an executive?") %>
    <%= member.check_box(:is_executive) %></br> -->
    <label>Executive Position*</label><br>
    <%= member.select(:executive_position, @executive, selected: @members.executive_position, prompt: 'Select Position') %><br>
        <%= member.submit %>
        <b><%= link_to "Cancel", '/members/executives'%></b>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My select tag options are declared in the application controller since I'm using the same select tag in multiple forms on other models

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

...
    def form_vars
      @majors = ['Accounting', 'Africana Studies', 'Anthropology', 'Architecture', 'Art', 'Art History', 'Athletic Training', 'Biology', 'Business Administration', 'Chemistry', 'Child and Family Development', 'Civil Engineering', 'Civil Engineering Technology', 'Computer Science', 'Computer Engineering', 'Construction Management', 'Criminal Justice', 'Dance', 'Earth and Environmental Sciences', 'Economics', 'Electrical Engineering', 'Electrical Engineering Technology', 'Elementary Education', 'English', 'Environmental Studies', 'Exercise Science', 'Finance', 'Fire Safety Engineering Technology', 'French', 'Geography', 'Geology', 'German', 'History', 'International Business', 'International Studies', 'Japanese', 'Latin American Studies', 'Management', 'Management Information Systems', 'Marketing', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics for Business', 'Mechanical Engineering', 'Mechanical Engineering Technology', 'Meteorology', 'Middle Grades Education', 'Music', 'Neurodiagnostics and Sleep Science', 'Nursing', 'Ops & Supply Chain Management', 'Pre-Law', 'Philosophy', 'Physics', 'Political Science', 'Psychology', 'Public Health', 'Religious Studies', 'Respiratory Therapy', 'Social Work', 'Sociology', 'Spanish', 'Special Education', 'Systems Engineering', 'Theatre']
      @executive = ['President', 'Vice President', 'Treasurer', 'Secretary', 'Strategic Advisor', 'Director of Strategic Partnerships', 'Director of Programs', 'Director of Public Relations', 'Director of Publications', 'Director of Community Service', 'Director of Fundraising', 'Historian', 'Digital Administrator']
      @grad_month = ['May', 'December']
    end
end
```

What's the best way to do this so that I can keep the array out of my form file but have working validations? I'm new to Rails so any other best practice tips are welcome Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valiadtions are the part of ActiveRecord. So, for validations work you may add all needed values into the model as follows:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAJORS = ['Accounting', 'Africana Studies', 'Anthropology', 'Architecture', 'Art', ...]
  EXECUTIVES = ['President', 'Vice President', 'Treasurer', 'Secretary', ...]
  GRAD_MONTH = ['May', 'December']

  validates :major, inclusion: { in: MAJORS, allow_blank: false }
  validates :executive_position, inclusion: { in: EXECUTIVES, allow_blank: false }
  validates :graduation_date, inclusion: { in: GRAD_MONTH, allow_blank: false }
end
```

Then in your form:

```
<%= f.select(:executive_position, Member::EXECUTIVES, selected: @members.executive_position, prompt: 'Select Position') %>
# ...
<%= member.select(:graduation_date, Members::GRAD_MONTH, selected: @members.graduation_date, prompt: 'Month') %>
# ...
<%= member.select(:major, Member::MAJORS, selected: @members.major, prompt: 'Select Major') %><br>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) about inclusion validation.

With that approcah you don't need to define values in `ApplicationController`.

Hope that will help.